# powershell combine where and or

Tags: powershell, office365

Im trying to buils a script to exclude users depending on their userprincipalname. I have started with the following script

```
Get-MsolUser -all | ?{($_.userprincipalname -notlike "*@domain1.com" -or $_.userprincipalname -notlike "*@domain2.com" -or $_.userprincipalname -notlike "*domain3.com")}
```

The code above does not exclude any users, it just ignores the where statement

BR
Carlos

Comment: You'll want `-and` instead of `-or`

Comment: You've also mangled "userprincipalname" as "userprincipalnme" in the second two clauses and missed off a " at the end.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, it works now with -and instead of -or. But why does it need to be -and? Dont follow that logic, since i want to check if their userprincipalname is one of them.

Comment: Because if the suffix is `@domain2.com`, then `-notlike "*@domain1.com"` is _still true_

Comment: @MarkWragg, sorry a typo on my side when copy/pasting the code and changing the domains to not show the real domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for example the suffix is `@domain2.com`, the two other clauses will still be `true` (because `@domain2.com` is still *not* `@domain1.com` or `@domain3.com`), so you'll want to use `-and` instead of `-or`:

```
Get-MsolUser -all | ?{($_.userprincipalname -notlike "*@domain1.com" -and $_.userprincipalname -notlike "*@domain2.com" -and $_.userprincipalname -notlike "*domain3.com")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, with a domain list :

```
$ExcludeDomain=@('domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com')

Get-MsolUser -all | where {($_.userprincipalname -split '@')[1] -notin $ExcludeDomain}
```